# How can I find teams with available working hours between two dates with sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I want to assign work to teams. In this, I need the date and time information of teams are free. But I was not able to pull it with SQL. In the pictures below, I have indicated table structure and what I want to get as a result. Thanks in advance for your help.

Table 1: Working Dates

```
ID  TEAM_NO     START_DATE          END_DATE
-----------------------------------------------------
1   A1          20.08.2021 13:00    20.08.2021 18:00
2   B1          19.08.2021 08:00    22.08.2021 18:00
3   G1          25.08.2021 08:00    25.08.2021 18:00
4   A2          17.08.2021 08:00    17.08.2021 18:00
5   A1          16.08.2021 08:00    16.08.2021 12:00
```

Table 2: Teams

```
ID  TEAM_NO     TEAM_NAME
--------------------------
1   A1          ALPHA1
2   A2          ALPHA2
3   B1          BETA1
4   B2          BETA2
5   G1          GAMMA1
```

Query: Between Two Dates

```
START_DATE          END_DATE
-------------------------------------
20.08.2021 08:00    20.08.2021 18:00
```

Result

```
TEAM_NO     FREE_DATETIME_START     FREE_DATETIME_END
----------------------------------------------------------
A1          20.08.2021 08:00        20.08.2021 13:00
G1          20.08.2021 08:00        20.08.2021 18:00
A2          20.08.2021 08:00        20.08.2021 18:00
```

Working Dates

[image: 1]

Teams

[image: 2]

Query

[image: 3]

Result

[image: 4]

Comment: Most people here want the sample table data and result as formatted text, not as images. (Can't copy-and-paste image text...) Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: @jarlh, I made the necessary adjustments. Thank you for alerting

Comment: A2 shouldn't be in your output.

Answer (score 0):

This is the typicall gaps and island problem. I give you an approach to solve your request

```
with ranges (HOURS) as (
  select TO_DATE('20.08.2021 08:00:00','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS') from dual
  union all
  select HOURS + interval '1' hour from ranges where HOURS < TO_DATE('20.08.2021 18:00:00','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
)
select
  TO_CHAR(min(r.HOURS),'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MM') as FREE_START_DATE, 
  TO_CHAR(max(r.HOURS),'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MM') as FREE_END_DATE
from ranges r
  cross join WORKING_DATES w
where case when r.HOURS >= w.START_DATE and r.HOURS <  w.END_DATE then 'Y' else 'N' end = 'N'
  and w.START_DATE >= TO_DATE('20.08.2021 08:00:00','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
group by TEAM_NO
```

First of all I created a recursive CTE (`ranges`) which artificially creates hours between your desired "Between two dates".

Then, I perform a cartesian product (`cross join`) between your `WORKING_DATES` table and `range`. This allows us to check if each hour was between the `START_DATE` and `END_DATE` for each register. I wrote the filter in a `case when` statement in order to let you understand better the meaning: `'Y'` means "working", and `'N'` means free time.

In addition, I added a filter to skip all those rows whose `START_DATE` was previous to the interval you are interested in.